# Отобразить значение под каждым столбиком гистограммы

Tags: python, matplotlib

Как отобразить значение под каждым столбиком?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10), dpi = 100)

ax.hist(x, bins=80)

ax.set_facecolor('seashell')
fig.set_facecolor('floralwhite')
fig.set_figwidth(10)    #  ширина Figure
fig.set_figheight(6)    #  высота Figure
ax=plt.gca()
plt.show()
x.clear()
```

[image: график]

Answer (score 0):

При

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10), dpi = 100)

ax.hist(x, bins=80)

ax.set_facecolor('seashell')
fig.set_facecolor('floralwhite')
fig.set_figwidth(10)    #  ширина Figure
fig.set_figheight(6)    #  высота Figure
ax=plt.gca()
plt.xticks(x, rotation=90) # <---
plt.show()
```

можно получить приблизительно то, что вы хотите (гистограмма, разумеется, у меня другая).
но вы должны понимать, что гистограмма - это не столбчатая диаграмма, выравнивание меток на гистограмме - то еще "удовольствие"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это помогло, но код стал грузиться секунд 5 (раньше моментально) и все цифры будто смазанные стали

Comment: ну мне описание симптомов ни о чём не говорит. Если есть возможность - либо дополните свой вопрос, либо, ещё лучше - задайте новый.